# Computer (win 8.1) starts by itself

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-task-scheduler, wake-up

My windows 8.1 desktop has suddenly decided to start itself during the night. It has not done that before and I suspect the behaviour might be new since new year.

1st of january 2015, it started 0615 (CET) - I thought it was odd and maybe a virus but did not investigate it further.

2nd of january 2015, it started 0550 (CET) - now I did some investigation. The following is what I found:

When runnning from cmd: schtasks/query

Scheduled Start                          2015-01-02 07:23:58    Ready

Scheduled Start With Network             2015-01-02 07:23:04    Ready

Then I looked at task scheduler and I can see that "Maintenance configurator" has multiple triggers defined. This is what triggered the start this morning.

Then I had a look at: C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\System.evtx

And there it says a lot of things which took place between 0447-0550. According to the logs it did boot (but didnt awake me) at 0447 and 0550 (here I did wake).

Here is some of the events from System.evtx:

The system time has changed to ‎2015‎-‎01‎-‎02T04:50:34.500000000Z from ‎2015‎-‎01‎-‎02T03:49:24.927685700Z.
Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.

The system has returned from a low power state.
Sleep Time: ‎2015‎-‎01‎-‎02T03:49:23.470269100Z
Wake Time: ‎2015‎-‎01‎-‎02T04:50:34.910310900Z
Wake Source: Unknown

Process C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (process ID:3028) reset policy scheme from {381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e} to {381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e}

Windows Defender cant find any threats. Have I gotten some malware or virus? How come Windows suddenly decided to start doing maintenance in the middle of the night? It has not happened before. The computer has been without electricity for about 1½ week prior to this as I have been away.

BRs

Comment: There is a switch somewhere on whether scheduled tasks can wake the computer, IIRC. Other than that, some BIOS setups offer an option to disable wakeup timers.

Comment: Yes, but that doesnt really explain why it just started happening. It has not done that before, so either Windows decided to change (maybe with the new year) or someone else did (not me).

Comment: have you tried [using the PowerCfg to find out what's waking it](http://serverfault.com/a/9200/2781)?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes, but it doesnt really say anything useful. "Wake history [0]". The devicequery command lists that it can be awoken by the network device.

Comment: What device(s) are wake armed?

Comment: keyboard, mouse, Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller (network adapter).

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 by design does maintenance such as disk optimization by waking the PC. Though that wasn't supposed to happen for unplugged laptops, I have seen comments that these tasks can wake the machine and drain the battery. MS has a thread on how to disable the tasks: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/how-to-permanently-disable-automatic-maintenance/d82d9d88-4383-4664-8dee-d2f1bb99ab41
Though it's possible the PC has a virus, it's more likely a Windows Update caused the issue.

BTW, you can get a "second opinion" from another antivirus -- Malwarebytes, for example, has a free download that scans only on request, so it won't bog down the PC by running in parallel with Defender. Kaspersky has the free Kaspersky Security Scan, http://www.kaspersky.com/virus-scanner

Answer (score 0):

It was not the daily maintenance of Microsoft Windows 8.1 (that I had disabled already) but it was the latest Razer Synapse 2.0 update that was causing the issue. Hopefully Razer comes soon with a update to bugfix this. Disabling all the Razer-devices + HID device in device-management (Tab: Power-management) to be able to wake the computer did the trick.